# Slow v-model for buefy input, v-model.lazy not working either

Tags: input, v-model, buefy

I have an a couple of input boxes that connect to data via v-model when a GO button is fired in my buefy form that is connected to my buefy data table.

the rows in my table can be 2000 to 3000, and my pagination cannot be less than 250 per page.

I tried using `v-model.lazy` but it seems like that doesn't work on `b-input`(buefy input field).

Now the problem is that the initial fill of the inputs isn't slow at all, but when the table is full and the user tries to edit the input fields there is a lag on the fields.

When I set the pagination to 50 results per page there is no lag, but my problem is that i can't have 50 results I must have 250 per page.

Can anyone think of a solution for this in Vue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So figured out that v-model.lazy wont work for custom components (seems like Vue limits it for custom components), that being said you would need to have `:value` + `@change.native`

and an example is below:

```
:value="data"
@change.native="data = $event.target.value"
```

Comment: Hello , facing the same issue with b-input , but it also affects all other inputs as well like b-autocomplete . Would be really helpful if you could also share how you got around that with all the inputs.

Comment: can you provide a link to your project @PadamSethia ?

Comment: Hey , thanks for the response. But go it working by breaking my inputs into sub components.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a slow `b-input` in a component with `b-table`.

For some reason even if i used
`<input v-model="item.value">`, it still was slow.

I **solve this problem** by creating subcomponent with this inputs.

Comment: Hi , could you share your sub component code , would be really helpful.
Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a separate row component, that way vue will only have to rerender your one row upon change. Otherwise vue will have to re-render every single row